# SpringBoot can't autowire SessionFactory in DAO class

Tags: java, spring-boot, sessionfactory

i'm coding a java application that should expose some rest api and making a db oracle connection.

I created a Class for defining DataSource, sessionFactory and transactionManager:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { //
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, //
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, //
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class BeanFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        // See: application.properties
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // See: application.properties
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        properties.put("current_session_context_class", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class"));
        properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults",false);

        // Fix Postgres JPA Error:
        // Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // Package contain entity classes
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "" });
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        //
        SessionFactory sf = factoryBean.getObject();
        System.out.println("## getSessionFactory: " + sf);
        return sf;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Then i Create a Class DAO not implemented yet, is just like a stub. I need sessionFactory before procede to create it:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ConnectionDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public Customer getCustomer(String name){



        return new Customer("","");
    }

    public Boolean setCustomer(String name, String surname){
        /*
         *
         */
        return false;
    }

}
```

And for last, i have the class with the API REST component. I tryed to create the DAO object as autowired or creating it by new, but it still don't work:

```
@RestController
public class TrainingRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionDAO daoConnection;

    @RequestMapping("/GetGroup")
    @GetMapping
    public Customer retrieve(@RequestParam(value="nome") String name){
        log.info("Retrieving " + name);
        return daoConnection.getCustomer(name);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/SetGroup")
    @PostMapping
    public boolean set(String name, String surname){
        log.info("Setting " + name + " " + surname);
        return daoConnection.setCustomer(name, surname);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the sessionFactory into the DAO class is not filled.
I also try deleting the autoWire into the BeanFactory class on the sessionFactory Bean, but it doesn't work.
Is there some Annotation that i'm missing?

If a make the daoConnection as Autowired, i get an exception executing the **public Customer retrieve()**:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder  at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(HibernateTransactionManager.java:399)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:342)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   com.test.ConnectionDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7579b8ee.getCustomer()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.test.TrainingRestController.retrieve(TrainingRestController.java:18)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

***That's transactionManager creation. I tried getting the currentSession from the sessionFactory***

[image: That's transactionManager creation. I tried getting the currentSession from the sessionFactory]

Comment: What exception are you getting, paste the stacktrace

Comment: I added the stack. take in mind, that i've the exception only if i autowire the daoConnection

Comment: Looks like a casting error more than an issue with autowiring. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476261/classcastexception-org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot-be-ca) or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621357/org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot-be-cast-to-org-springfram?noredirect=1&lq=1) could help.

Comment: infact if a remove:

@Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

from the BeanFactory class, i have no more crash, but the filling of sessionFactory still doesn't work